# When creating new table and field in vba Access 2000. Getting Error Data Type Conversion Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a new table with a few field on vba for Access 2000. I am able to create the table and a field when the data type of the field is Text But i need it to be Number. when I am changing the data type from Text to Number it gives me the error Data Type Conversion Error. Any Help would be Appreciated. Thanks

```
Public Sub CreateNewDB()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field

'Initialize the Contractor table

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("new test table")

'Specify the fields
With tdf

'Create Sequence No Fied
 ' Set fld = .CreateField("Sequence No", dbText, 10) ' This works 
Set fld = .CreateField("Sequence No", dbNumber, Long INteger) ' this gives me an error 
.Fields.Append fld

End With

'save  the table
db.TableDefs.Append tdf
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try dbLong instead of dbNumber.  [Reference](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html)

Here's code to set the PK on a newly created table:

```
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(sLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, sRemoteTableName, sConnect)
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
sExec = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK ON [" & sLocalTableName & "]"
For iPK = 0 To iPkfldCount - 1
    sPKfields = sPKfields & "[" & CurrentDb.TableDefs(sLocalTableName).Fields(iPK).Name & "],"
Next
sPKfields = Left(sPKfields, Len(sPKfields) - 1)     ' strip trailing comma
CurrentDb.Execute sExec & " (" & sPKfields & ")"
```

after you set the PK fields, you shouldn't need to index or set to No Duplicates.  All PKs work that way.

Comment: Thanks for the Help Beth. Can you help me with one more question. How do you set the Primary key and set the Indexed to Yes (NO Duplicates)