# Invalid field Data type when use TableDef.CreateField Method VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to add a series of fields to a Access 2016 Table, but keep encountering the error:

```
Runtime error '3259'
Invalid field data type
```

I originally specified the data type as dbNumeric but changed it to dbDecimal to see if that made a difference.  The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180929/how-do-i-create-a-decimal-field-in-access-with-alter-table) for CreateFields did not solve my problem, though I did not try the SQL. It did not. Here is the code:

```
Sub BOD_Variables()

    Dim myDBS
    Dim myTable As TableDef
    Dim myTableName As String

    myTableName = "BOD_Data"
    Set myDBS = CurrentDb
    Set myTable = myDBS.TableDefs(myTableName)

    Dim myField As Field
    Dim myVariableNames As Variant

    myVariableNames = Array("Blank_4_SampleVol", ... "BOD_ Concentration _OUT")

    Dim iCount As Integer

    For iCount = LBound(myVariableNames) To UBound(myVariableNames)
    Debug.Print myVariableNames(iCount)

        Set myField = myTable.CreateField(myVariableNames(iCount), dbDecimal) 'Originally specified dbNumeric for data type.
        myTable.Fields.Append myField
    Next  
End Sub
```

I attempted to replace the call to the Array(index) with:

```
        Set myField = myTable.CreateField("Blank_4_SampleVol", dbNumeric)
```

Still get the same error.

I tried specifying the length as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555771/when-creating-new-table-and-field-in-vba-access-2000-getting-error-data-type-co), but that did not correct problem. Documentation on CreateField says it ignores field length when field type is dbNumberic.

Any ideas of what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How far into the for loop do you get before the error?  Need more info on the debugging you've done.

Comment: I think using 'dbDouble' will more than meet your needs and should execute without error - no need for specifying length

Comment: Note that your code is using DAO objects (e.g., `TableDef`) whereas the (working) code in my answer is using ADOX objects.

Comment: Sorry, took couple days off. It chokes on first iteration. @dbmitch, tried your simple approach and that worked! If you put it as an answer, I will select it as THE answer.

Comment: No problem - looks like someone closed this question off so I can't add an answer. You can just upvote my comment if you want.

Answer (score 1):

While it remains true that DAO does not seem to expose the required properties to create a `Decimal` field, even if we try using a `DAO.Field2` object, the following ADOX code does create a `Decimal` field (tested with Access 2010):

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub AddNewDecimalField()
    Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
    cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    Dim tbl As ADOX.Table
    Set tbl = cat.Tables("MyTable")
    Dim col As New ADOX.Column
    col.Name = "MyNewDecimalField"
    col.Type = adNumeric  ' note: not adDecimal
    col.Precision = 18
    col.NumericScale = 8
    tbl.Columns.Append col
End Sub
```

Or, we could just use a DDL query ...

```vbs
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute _
        "ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyNewDecimalField DECIMAL(18,8)"
```

... as Andre suggests in his answer.

Comment: Gord, thanks for your time. I suspect I will use your more sophisticated approach in the future. I have a bit of a newbie question: how do I implement or reference ADOX? Access is interpreting ADOX.Table as a user-defined type right now. Thanks, Phillip

Comment: In the VBA development environment you need to do `Tools > References...` and add a reference for "Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security". Note that your specific question is something of  special case: Most of the time DAO offers more complete coverage of Access features than ADOX does, it's just that support for `Decimal` fields is strangely lacking in DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [link](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html) in your linked question, and read the footnote #7 for DECIMAL:

> [7] Not available in the Access query interface or DAO. Use ADO to Execute the DDL query statement.

So you'd use something like this:

```
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN " & myVariableNames(iCount) & " DECIMAL (20,6);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
```

Decimal fields <s>have</s> had (see comment below) their issues, see [Avoid Using Decimal Field Size in Microsoft Access Tables](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/database-design/decimal_data_type/index.htm)
or http://allenbrowne.com/bug-08.html

Long or Double or Currency may be better options.

Comment: re: "Decimal fields have their issues" - Both of those references are quite out of date (circa Access 2000 and 2003). Access 2010 does not have a problem sorting Decimal values, and exporting to text does not fail, although it does export the values with string delimiters. Allen's contributions to the Access community are legendary - and most deservedly so - but he has been retired for many years now and things that were true five (or more) versions ago are not necessarily true today.

Comment: Thank you for this information, @Gord!